# Using GET to retrieve Data from my Webpage

Tags: post, get, iot, esp8266

I'm trying to use an ESP8266 NodeMCU to retrieve data from a database on my web page to control a LED. I'm struggling with the code on both sides for the ESP8266 to ask for the data and the web page to return it.  I have the web page and database built.  Here is the relevant bit of the server side PHP file, which isn't working....

```
 if(!empty($_GET['mode']) && !empty($_GET['brightness']))
    {
        $mode = $_GET['mode'];
        $brightness = $_GET['brightness'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM config ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 (mode, brightness) 
    $result = $conn->query($sql);   
SELECT fields FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;

        VALUES ('".$mode."', '".$brightness."')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "1" . $row["id"]."<br>";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }
    $conn->close();

<code>
and on the ESP8266 side....
```

`getData = "?mode=" "&brightness=";  
  Link = "http://***.com/Feed.php" + getData;
  http.begin(Link);     //Specify request destination
  int httpCode = http.GET();            
  String payload = http.getString();   
  Mode = payload.substring(0,3); 
  String Brightness = payload.substring (4,6);`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I changed my approach and got it working.  Instead of trying to return data from the web page to the ESP8266 I displayed the data on a very simple page....

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","*****","*****","*****");    
if (mysqli_connect_errno())  {  echo "Failed to connect to config: " . mysqli_connect_error();  } 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM config ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $mode = $row[mode]; $brightness = $row[brightness]; $speed = $row[speed]; 
    print $mode;
    print $brightness;
    print $speed;
}
    ?>
```

and then had the ESP download the entire page and parsed out the data using substring like so...

```
HTTPClient http;    //Declare object of class HTTPClient
Link = "http://*****.com/*****.php";
http.begin(Link);     //Specify request destination
int httpCode = http.GET();            //Send the request
String payload = http.getString();    //Get the response payload
Mode = payload.substring(156,158).toInt();
Speed = payload.substring(158,160).toInt();
Brightness = payload.substring(160,162).toInt();
```